# How to redirect each type of member to a specific page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am using membership plugin and I have created 4 members (`free`, `silver`, `gold`, `platinum`).

All users currently redirect to the same page but I want to redirect each user to their own page (e.g. free user should redirect to free page, gold user redirect to gold page etc.).

Is is possible? If yes, How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set each type redirect url and that url pass in wp-login.php page so on a specific page you can redirect.

Comment: I am new on wordpress can you please how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Use "**login redirect**" hook to redirect an user after login.
[codex reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

Or you can use "wp login" hook to redirect user after login.

```
function your_function_name($user_login, $user) {

    // code to check membership of an user.
    // use wp_redirect to redirect conditionally to specific pages..

}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function_name', 10, 2);
```

Comment: but  I want to redirect each member to their own page and the above code is redirecting users. Means its checking role but I want to redirect with level instead of member role

Comment: You should add code to check member role, it depends on which plugin you are using for membership level.